# z being replaced with %7a in attachments with cfmail

Tags: coldfusion

i have a simple email sender using coldfusion 10 that first allows users to upload and then attach those files to the email.

those files are attached like;

```
<CFMAILPARAM FILE="#file#" DISPOSITION="attachment" TYPE="#type#/#subtype#">
```

today we uploaded and sent out two attachments with filenames like;

> Blah_Blah_something_off_Brazil_Site-Table_4.docx
>
> Blah_something_off_Brazil_Sites-map.pdf

but in outlook/live mail the attachments were being shown as;

> ATT00247.docx
>
> ATT00249.pdf

i've had trouble before with outlook/live mail and attachments being given different filenames, but that was down to spaces in the filename. these files have no spaces. so i had a look at the email source, which was showing the attachments as;

> Blah_Blah_something_off_Bra%7ail_Site-Table_4.docx
>
> Blah_something_off_Bra%7ail_Sites-map.pdf

its replaced the z's with the %7a

i had a look at the email source in thunderbird, which was displaying the names correctly, but even there, in the source, the filenames had the z's replaced with %7a

so i created a text file, saved it as brazil.txt, uploaded and sent it out

in the email source in outlook and thunderbird, it came through as;

> bra%7ail.txt

i know that a %7a is a url encoded z. the uploaded/saved on server file doesn't have that - it has the z. its only when emailed as an attachment that the z's get changed to %7a

anyone have any idea whats going on?! why doesn't coldfusion cfmail like the letter z?!

edit - so i just created a text file called

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.txt

and it came through as;

> abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy%7aABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.txt

so its only lowercase z's that get changed ...

**addition**

well, i fixed it - removing the TYPE="#type#/#subtype#" did the job, but i don't why that was causing trouble. below is what is was filling in for the type/subtype ( which came from the upload/cffile ) for each of the files;

```
zanzibar1.txt - text/plain
Blah_Something_off_Brazil_Sites-map-test1.pdf - application/pdf
Blah_Blah_Something_off_Brazil_Site-Table_4-test1.docx - application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1.txt - text/plain
```

all the email clients i've tested don't seem to care about the type/subtype missing and they all display the correct filename. but i don't see whats wrong with type/subtype ...

Comment: Even though the file is saved with the correct name, something seems to be doing a replace of a "z" somewhere. Have you looked at the query that's generating the data for the file attachment? Have you tested a file with multiple "z"s in the name?

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno i tested with zanzibar.txt and it comes out %7aan%7aibar.txt ... theres nothing in the queries or when i upload/save that would make this change to the filename ... i'm stumped!

Comment: As a test, try saving the uploaded file to the ColdFusion server before it gets mailed. Is the `z` in the filename encoded?

Comment: @Miguel-F it is already saved to the server before it gets emailed, and the filename is normal

Comment: What is your #type# and #subtype#? Have you tried hard coding those?

Comment: Also... 1) Try hard coding the #file# value and 2) can you post your cfmail code?

Comment: hi @Jules i've added some info above, but i've solved the issue by removing the whole type/subtype bit ... i don't know why that was causing the problem, but at least its working now!

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion. I looked through some code I have, and left the type out as well. Funky bug you found - glad you got the workaround!

Comment: @luke you should add an answer to this question with the details that you found. That will be easier for people to find in the future.